# Applying changes of ToMany<E> relation to objectbox store in dart

Tags: dart, flutter-test, objectbox, data-access-object, flutter-objectbox

In project i use latest Dart version with *objectbox*: ^1.0.0:

```
@Entity
class Node{

 ...
  @Transient()
  final List<Edge> _edges = List<Edge>.empty(growable: true);
 
  final relEdges = ToMany<Edge>();
 ...

}

@Entity
class Edge{
 ...

  @Transient()
  final List<Node> _nodes = List<Node>.empty(growable: true);

  @Backlink()
  final relNodes = ToMany<Node>();
 ...
}
```

after nodes and edges are created. Nodes are assigned to the list of nodes in edge object(reverse in nodeObject) and then in DAO layer they are (re)applied to *relList*(ToMany) of objectbox.

Actual put:

**main_test.dart:**

```
 // nodes and edge are created
 node1.dao.create(node1);
 node2.dao.create(node2);
 node3.dao.create(node3);
 edge..nodes.addAll([node1,node2]);
 edge.dao.create(edge);
 node1.dao.update(node1..edges.add(edge));
 node2.dao.update(node2..edges.add(edge));
 ...
 // removes edge from node2's edge list
 node2..edges.removeWhere((element) {
  return element.uuid == edge.uuid;
 });
 node3..edges.add(edge);
 // this placement also didn't change anything
 //await node2.dao.update(node2);
 //await node3.dao.update(node3);
 // or remove(1) and add(node3)
 edge..edges.clear();
 edge..edges.addAll([node1,node3]);

 await node2.dao.update(node2);
 await node3.dao.update(node3);
 await node1.dao.update(node1);
 await edge.dao.update(edge)
 ...
```

**edgeDao.dart**

```
    ...
    element.relNodes.clear();
    element.relNodes.addAll(edges);
    ...
```

**nodeDao.dart**

```
    ...
    element.relEdges.clear();
    element.relEdges.addAll(nodes);
    ...
```

**databaseConnector.dart:**

```
 // Box<(Element)> _box; is alrady initialized
 ...
 // it is implemented the same way, for Edge class
 // create works the same way
 Future<void> update(Node element) async {
    this._box.put(element);
  }
 ...
```

***add*** operation works properly, just like update, before i try to save changes of edge relations, after old node is removed from ToMany and new one is added (this crashes every further put operation). I get following error from objectbox (x3):

```
>package:objectbox/src/native/bindings/helpers.dart 78:9                                                        ObjectBoxNativeError.throwMapped
>package:objectbox/src/native/bindings/helpers.dart 50:48                                                       throwLatestNativeError
>package:objectbox/src/native/bindings/helpers.dart 17:5                                                        checkObx
>package:objectbox/src/native/box.dart 461:7                                                                    InternalBoxAccess.relRemove
>package:objectbox/src/relations/to_many.dart 195:33                                                            ToMany.applyToDb.<fn>
>dart:collection                                                                                                _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
>package:objectbox/src/relations/to_many.dart 168:15                                                            ToMany.applyToDb
>package:objectbox/src/native/box.dart 365:13                                                                   Box._putToManyRelFields.<fn>
>dart:collection                                                                                                _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach
>package:objectbox/src/native/box.dart 362:37                                                                   Box._putToManyRelFields
> ...

>ObjectBoxException: 404 404: Unknown native error
```

neither put() nor **applyToDB()** work. I even tried to use ***clear()*** and then to ***addAll*** to ToMany from list object. Any suggestions why this happens?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Can you share the actual code that does the put? Also looking at the examples for this may help: https://docs.objectbox.io/relations

Comment: So the actual issue is that when removing and then adding something to a relation, the put call fails? What if you also put after the remove and before the add? Anyhow, as it appears you have a full example, would you mind sharing it so we can more easily reproduce this? You can also create an issue at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues.

Comment: When i try to add new record only after i've done remove+update operation , it works fine. So the only problem is when remove and update are run at the same time. Unfortunately i can't share a full example, it's only a tiny part of my whole project .

Comment: Actually, removing and adding before a single put works: added a test at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/commit/f8eca24307f8fe12c99cee43b915aa181f9df323
Can you double check your code?
Note that you do not need to update the backlink ToMany. It is updated automatically when the ToMany it points to changes. Or vice versa.

Comment: I'm going to check, why this operation doesn't work in my tests and when i find the answer, i'll add it here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case after remove, i have to update the **`ToMany`** relation. Only then i can add a new value. When i find the reason, why it these operations don't work in my tests, i'll update the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).